# Using mpirun on OS X on one machine

Tags: macos, openmpi

I have trouble using `mpirun` in single-machine mode on OS X. When running my program using `mpirun -np 5 my_program` I get the following error output:

```
[...-MacBook-Pro.local:85936] [0,0,0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Timeout in file /SourceCache/openmpi/openmpi-8/openmpi/orte/mca/pls/base/pls_base_orted_cmds.c at line 275
[...-MacBook-Pro.local:85936] [0,0,0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Timeout in file /SourceCache/openmpi/openmpi-8/openmpi/orte/mca/pls/rsh/pls_rsh_module.c at line 1158
[...-MacBook-Pro.local:85936] [0,0,0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Timeout in file /SourceCache/openmpi/openmpi-8/openmpi/orte/mca/errmgr/hnp/errmgr_hnp.c at line 90
mpirun noticed that job rank 1 with PID 85940 on node ...-MacBook-Pro.local exited on signal 6 (Abort trap). 
2 additional processes aborted (not shown)
```

Apparently, by default `mpirun` uses `rsh` for connecting to machines. I tried using `ssh` instead, but it didn't help:

```
mpirun --mca pls_rsh_agent ssh -np 5 my_program
```

Then, I tried using the shared-memory (`sm`) BTL, which didn't help either:

```
mpirun --mca btl self,sm -np 5 my_program
```

Finally, I tried using a machine file to specify that I only want to use `localhost`, which didn't help either:

```
mpirun -np 5 -machinefile machinefile.local my_program
```

Here, `machinefile.local` only contains `localhost` on the (single) first line.

In all of the above cases, I get the above timeout error.

Also, I verified that my Mac OS X firewall wasn't running and that I could ssh into my machine.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're using a version of OpenMPI from fink, is that right?   Do you still have the original 1.2.x MPI in /usr/bin and /usr/lib?  The first place to look for weird launching issues is conflicting versions of the MPI libraries.

First try something simple like `/usr/bin/mpirun -np 5 hostname`, and then wherever your fink mpirun is do the same thing: `/path/to/fink/mpirun -np 5 hostname`, just to make sure the two MPI launchers work on a non-MPI program.  Then do an `ldd` on `my_program`; which libraries is it linking to?  Use the appropriate `mpirun` for those libraries, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall and make sure it allows mpirun to establish inbound and outbound connections.